# Cannot transfer data from Dataprep to Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to transfer a 15GB `csv` file from `Dataprep` to `Google BigQuery`. However I get the following error: [image: screenshot of error message]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: As @Pentium10 noted, please submit bugs at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190822&template=0

Comment: The post would be more searchable for future users if text can be used instead of screenshot of the error: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: It seems as your csv has rows of different length. As the error says, line 7374 contains 52 fields, whereas the previous contained only 48. Is your data the results of appending multiple datasets? If so, are their fields equal?